# IllegalArgumentException on creating a Group in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, illegalstateexception, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to create a new Group in Liferay using the method [addGroup](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/GroupLocalServiceUtil.html#addGroup%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29) of the class [GroupLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/GroupLocalServiceUtil.html#addGroup%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29). I pass the parameter types according to the docs, however it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` inexplicably. Here is my plain code:

```
ServiceContext sc = new ServiceContext();
sc.setScopeGroupId(10);
GroupLocalServiceUtil.addGroup(11101, "com.liferay.portal.model.Group", 0, 0, "aaa","foo", description, 
            10, null, true, true, sc);
```

What is wrong? Could I set the ServiceContext parameter to null?

**Update:** The version I use is 6.1. The stacktrace of the Exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Something went wrong: 
at com.pro.liferay.startUpHook.ReadGroupFromCsv.addData(ReadGroupFromCsv.java:69)
at com.pro.liferay.startUpHook.CreateUserOnStartUp.run(CreateUserOnStartUp.java:27)
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.InvokerSimpleAction.run(InvokerSimpleAction.java:42)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.initEvent(HookHotDeployListener.java:1177)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.initEvents(HookHotDeployListener.java:1239)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.initPortalProperties(HookHotDeployListener.java:1595)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(HookHotDeployListener.java:563)
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HookHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(HookHotDeployListener.java:273)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.addGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:276)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy23.addGroup(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalServiceUtil.addGroup(GroupLocalServiceUtil.java:300)
at com.pro.liferay.startUpHook.customutils.GroupUtil.addGroup(GroupUtil.java:63)
at com.pro.liferay.startUpHook.customutils.GroupUtil.addGroup(GroupUtil.java:69)
at com.pro.liferay.startUpHook.ReadGroupFromCsv.addData(ReadGroupFromCsv.java:67)
... 30 more
```

Comment: As you have the exception: Where is it thrown - have you inspected Liferay's source code at that location? It might be obvious what's causing this exception if you'd inspect that location. At least give the stacktrace and the version you're using

Comment: @OlafKock: Look at my Update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using **Liferay 6.1.1**, and looking line 276 in `GroupLocalServiceImpl.addGroup` i can see this:

```java
if (className.equals(Group.class.getName())) {
    if (!site && (liveGroupId == 0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // this is line 276
    }
}
```

So you must be setting `site=false` and `liveGroupId=0`.

Anyway, i used to use this piece of code in order to create sites (i repeat, **Liferay 6.1.1**), and it works perfectly fine as far as i can remember ;)

```java
GroupLocalServiceUtil.addGroup(userId, Group.class.getName(), 0, "title","description",GroupConstants.TYPE_SITE_OPEN, "/siteFriendlyUrl", true, true, new ServiceContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure `url` can be null?
- Could you replace the class name with Group.class.getName() ?

Comment: According to the docs friendlyUrl can be optionally null. I changed the class name as you propose above, but it had no effect. Still an Exception.